# Typescript interface objects to string array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, object

i have a interface named UiDataUpdateFunction.In the code defined like this.

```
 @Effect()
      bulkCreateUIDataUpdateFunction$ = this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType<UIDataUpdateFunctionActions.BulkCreateUIDataUpdateFunction>(
          UIDataUpdateFunctionActions.ActionTypes.BulkCreateUIDataUpdateFunction
        ),
        mergeMap((action) => {
          const params = {
          body: action.payload.uiDataUpdateFunctions
          };
          return this.UIDataUpdateFunctionApi.bulkCreate(params).pipe(
            mergeMap((uiDataUpdateFunctions: UiDataUpdateFunction) => {
              console.log(uiDataUpdateFunctions)
```

this code's console log objects in array.
[image: console log]

I want it should be return as string array. When i tried define like this uiDataUpdateFunctions: UiDataUpdateFunction[] its give a an error **(**The independent variable of type 'OperatorFunction<UiDataUpdateFunction[], Action>' cannot be assigned to a parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<UiDataUpdateFunction, Action>'. The type 'UiDataUpdateFunction[]' is missing the following properties of type 'UiDataUpdateFunction': id, projectId, uiDataStoreId.**)**. So i tried do it like this

```
mergeMap((uiDataUpdateFunctions: UiDataUpdateFunction[]= [{
      id: '',
      projectId: '',
      uiDataStoreId: '',
    }])
```

but its still give same error.I also tried doing .map() to convert to array on uiDataUpdateFunctions. Probally i can't write correctly. Shortly i want to return objects coming from the interface as a string array. What should i do for this ?

Comment: [Please replace/supplement images of code/logs/errors with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218)

Comment: Without seeing the definition of `UiDataUpdateFunction` this becomes impossible to answer and it's not clear what your expected result would be - what do you mean by "I want it should be return as string array." ? You try to cast it to an array when it already seems to be an array. With the code I see, the behavior looks as expected. Try to update your examples with complete code and what exactly your expectation would be.